# MongoDB dirty journal file causing assert failure

Tags: mongodb

Running MongoDB 2.6.1, I'm having an issue where the dirty journal file is causing an assertion. The issue is impacting 2 of my 3 nodes on a replica set, and the remaining healthy node is stuck in SECONDARY.  When I try to run with --repair, the repair aborts because of existing dirty journals.  What is the best way to fix this?  Is it possible to remove the offending operation from the journal?

```
2014-12-14T06:09:57.075+0000 [repl writer worker 1] Assertion: 13111:wrong type for field (readReceipts.key) 17 != 9
2014-12-14T06:09:57.083+0000 [repl writer worker 1] cricket.feeds 0xe93423 0xe3fe29 0xe26a01 0xe26aac 0x7c7ef3 0x7cf2cb 0x7cb88e 0xad26e2 0xae010b 0xadb4d4 0xae2335 0xad6e0e 0xc256b5 0xc5df3d 0xc5d9c0 0xe36338 0xedf8eb 0x7ff5e6a00e9a 0x7ff5e58e32ed 
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x23) [0xe93423]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x1a9) [0xe3fe29]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x91) [0xe26a01]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod() [0xe26aac]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod() [0x7c7ef3]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo20compareElementValuesERKNS_11BSONElementES2_+0x4cb) [0x7cf2cb]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11mutablebson7Element22compareWithBSONElementERKNS_11BSONElementEb+0x34e) [0x7cb88e]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ModifierSet7prepareENS_11mutablebson7ElementERKNS_10StringDataEPNS_17ModifierInterface8ExecInfoE+0x412) [0xad26e2]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12UpdateDriver6updateERKNS_10StringDataEPNS_11mutablebson8DocumentEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_11FieldRefSetE+0x20b) [0xae010b]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugEPNS_12UpdateDriverEPNS_14CanonicalQueryE+0x724) [0xadb4d4]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14UpdateExecutor7executeEv+0x75) [0xae2335]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugE+0x1e) [0xad6e0e]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21applyOperation_inlockERKNS_7BSONObjEbb+0xdd5) [0xc256b5]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset8SyncTail9syncApplyERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0x29d) [0xc5df3d]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x50) [0xc5d9c0]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x548) [0xe36338]
 /usr/local/bin/mongod() [0xedf8eb]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7ff5e6a00e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7ff5e58e32ed]
2014-12-14T06:09:57.083+0000 [repl writer worker 1] ERROR: writer worker caught exception:  :: caused by :: 13111 wrong type for field (readReceipts.key) 17 != 9 on: { ts: Timestamp 1418522384000|2, h: -1705807359185394341, v: 2, op: "u", ns: "cricket.feeds", o2: { _id: ObjectId('5479863209472593bb242a9e') }, o: { $set: { readReceipts.key: Timestamp 1418522384000|1 } } }
2014-12-14T06:09:57.083+0000 [repl writer worker 1] Fatal Assertion 16360
2014-12-14T06:09:57.083+0000 [repl writer worker 1] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have data backups?  Bring down your faulty secondaries, delete the data on one of them, and bring it back up (just one) -- this will start the initial re-sync process.  If all is well, at this point you will have 1 primary and 1 secondary.  Before you do this, verify that the size of your oplog window is large enough to complete the initial sync process.  Once this is all back to normal, do the same for your second Secondary.

Comment: The data shouldn't be lost.  The problem is the invalid operation stuck in the journal.  What if I deleted the journal files with: rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/journal/*

Comment: Deleting the journal files wasn't sufficient, I did have to delete all of the data using: rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*.  That stopped the assertions and launched, enabling my healthy secondary to take over as primary and everything is back up.